# Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy not connected

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am using the following code to create a Custom Post Type and a Custom Taxonomy:

```
// Register Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_resource' );
function cptui_register_my_cpt_resource() {
    register_post_type( 'resource', array(
        'label' => 'Resources',
        'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resource', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'page-attributes',' post-formats' ),
        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'Resources',
            'singular_name' => 'Resource',
            'menu_name' => 'Resources',
            'add_new' => 'Add Resource',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Resource',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Resource',
            'new_item' => 'New Resource',
            'view' => 'View Resource',
            'view_item' => 'View Resource',
            'search_items' => 'Search Resources',
            'not_found' => 'No Resources Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Resources Found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Resource',
        )
    )); 
}

// Register Taxonomy 
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_resource_categories' );
function cptui_register_my_taxes_resource_categories() {
    register_taxonomy( 'resource categories', array( 0 => 'resource' ), array( 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Resource Categories',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'labels' => array (
            'search_items' => 'Resource Category',
            'popular_items' => '',
            'all_items' => '',
            'parent_item' => '',
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'edit_item' => '',
            'update_item' => '',
            'add_new_item' => '',
            'new_item_name' => '',
            'separate_items_with_commas' => '',
            'add_or_remove_items' => '',
            'choose_from_most_used' => '',
        )
    )); 
}
```

Everything appears to be working on the surface, I *can* connect a category to a resource, but when I try to query them as such:

```
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'resource',
    'category_name' => 'recruiting'

);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I don't get any results.  Any ideas?

Comment: taxonomy names can't contain spaces, only lower case letters and underscore are valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Custom Taxonomy name?

Try the following code, replace `taxonomy_name` with whatever your actual taxonomy name is.

```
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'resource',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
            'field'    => 'slug', //Select taxonomy term by slug( you can also use name/id)
            'terms'    => 'term-slug/category -slug',
        ),

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[Custom taxonomy parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I did not use the custom taxonomy NAME which is "resource categories", an apparently those can contain spaces because this worked:

```
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'resource',
    'resource categories' => 'recruiting'
);
```

Comment: I imagine you may run into trouble down the rode with spaces in your taxonomy. You really should use underscores.